# Getting instagram followers and followings on python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I've a code that gets instagram followers and followings at the end it gives a comparision list but there is a problem. Generally, it cannot get all of the followers and following for example there are 45 followers but it only gets 42 41 followers etc. How can i prevent this? This is my code but please don't see the if conditions it is for threading.

```
 def compare_profile(self,profile):
        self.should_stop = False
        while self.should_stop==False:
            print("Profil analiz fonksiyonu başladı.")
            self.driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{profile}/')
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            time.sleep(10)
            self.driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{profile}/followers/')
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            time.sleep(10)
            followers_panel = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
            last_ht, ht = 0, 1
            while last_ht != ht:
                if self.should_stop == True:
                    break
                last_ht = ht
                ht = self.driver.execute_script(""" arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);return arguments[0].scrollHeight; """,followers_panel)
                try:
                    if self.should_stop == True:
                        break
                    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_aanq"]')))
                    if self.should_stop == True:
                        break
                    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p  _abc0 _abcm")))
                    if self.should_stop == True:
                        break
                    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="_aano"])')))
                except:
                    if self.should_stop == True:
                        break
                    time.sleep(random.randint(6,10))
                if self.should_stop == True:
                    break
                time.sleep(random.randint(4,8))
                if self.should_stop == True:
                    break
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="x1i10hfl x1qjc9v5 xjbqb8w xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x13fuv20 xu3j5b3 x1q0q8m5 x26u7qi x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xdl72j9 x2lah0s xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x1n2onr6 x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x1q0g3np x87ps6o x1lku1pv x1a2a7pz xh8yej3 x193iq5w x1lliihq x1dm5mii x16mil14 xiojian x1yutycm"])')))
                if self.should_stop == True:
                    break
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'(//div[@class="x1i10hfl x1qjc9v5 xjbqb8w xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x13fuv20 xu3j5b3 x1q0q8m5 x26u7qi x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xdl72j9 x2lah0s xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x1n2onr6 x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x1q0g3np x87ps6o x1lku1pv x1a2a7pz xh8yej3 x193iq5w x1lliihq x1dm5mii x16mil14 xiojian x1yutycm"])')))
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            list_of_followers = list(map(lambda x: x.text, self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="x1i10hfl x1qjc9v5 xjbqb8w xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x13fuv20 xu3j5b3 x1q0q8m5 x26u7qi x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xdl72j9 x2lah0s xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x1n2onr6 x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x1q0g3np x87ps6o x1lku1pv x1a2a7pz xh8yej3 x193iq5w x1lliihq x1dm5mii x16mil14 xiojian x1yutycm"])')))
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Takipçiler çekildi")
            print("Toplam takipçi: ",len(list_of_followers))
            # Following List
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            self.driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{profile}/')
            time.sleep(10)
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            self.driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{profile}/following/')
            time.sleep(10)
            following_panel = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]')
            last_ht, ht = 0, 1
            while last_ht != ht:
                if self.should_stop == True:
                    break
                last_ht = ht
                ht = self.driver.execute_script(""" arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);return arguments[0].scrollHeight; """,following_panel)
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_aanq"]')))
                    if self.should_stop == True:
                        break
                    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p  _abc0 _abcm")))
                    if self.should_stop == True:
                        break
                    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="_aano"])')))
                except:
                    if self.should_stop == True:
                        break
                    time.sleep(random.randint(6,10))
                if self.should_stop == True:
                    break
                time.sleep(random.randint(4,8))
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'(//div[@class="x1i10hfl x1qjc9v5 xjbqb8w xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x13fuv20 xu3j5b3 x1q0q8m5 x26u7qi x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xdl72j9 x2lah0s xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x1n2onr6 x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x1q0g3np x87ps6o x1lku1pv x1a2a7pz xh8yej3 x193iq5w x1lliihq x1dm5mii x16mil14 xiojian x1yutycm"])')))
                if self.should_stop == True:
                    break
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'(//div[@class="x1i10hfl x1qjc9v5 xjbqb8w xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x13fuv20 xu3j5b3 x1q0q8m5 x26u7qi x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xdl72j9 x2lah0s xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x1n2onr6 x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x1q0g3np x87ps6o x1lku1pv x1a2a7pz xh8yej3 x193iq5w x1lliihq x1dm5mii x16mil14 xiojian x1yutycm"])')))
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            list_of_followings = list(map(lambda x: x.text, self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="x1i10hfl x1qjc9v5 xjbqb8w xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x13fuv20 xu3j5b3 x1q0q8m5 x26u7qi x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xdl72j9 x2lah0s xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x1n2onr6 x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x1q0g3np x87ps6o x1lku1pv x1a2a7pz xh8yej3 x193iq5w x1lliihq x1dm5mii x16mil14 xiojian x1yutycm"])')))
            print("Takip edilenler çekildi")
            print("Toplam takip edilen: ",len(list_of_followings))

            # Data Frame listesi oluşturma
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            yoursnofollow = list(set(list_of_followers) - set(list_of_followings))
            theynofollow = list(set(list_of_followings) - set(list_of_followers))
            ltheynofollow, lyoursnofollow, llist_of_followers, llist_of_followings = len(theynofollow), len(
                yoursnofollow), len(list_of_followers), len(list_of_followings)
            max_len = max(ltheynofollow, lyoursnofollow, llist_of_followers, llist_of_followings)
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            if not max_len == ltheynofollow:
                theynofollow.extend([''] * (max_len - ltheynofollow))
            if not max_len == lyoursnofollow:
                yoursnofollow.extend([''] * (max_len - lyoursnofollow))
            if not max_len == llist_of_followers:
                list_of_followers.extend([''] * (max_len - llist_of_followers))
            if not max_len == llist_of_followings:
                list_of_followings.extend([''] * (max_len - llist_of_followings))
            if self.should_stop == True:
                break
            tablo = {'Takipçiler': list_of_followers, 'Takip Ettiklerin': list_of_followings,
                     'Seni Takip Etmeyenler': theynofollow, 'Senin Takip Etmediklerin': yoursnofollow}
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=tablo)
            print(df)
            df.to_excel(f"{profile}.xlsx")
            self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
            break
        if self.should_stop == True:
            mbox.showinfo("Stopped", "The bot has stopped.")
        else:
            mbox.showinfo("Function Finished", "Function successfully finished.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instagrapi.
I was also facing this problem but after some research I got it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).